# Handling NA in groupby + transform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Edit (Jul/2021):**

> Back in the days (Jun/2017) I filled an [issue on Pandas' Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17093#issuecomment-859993083). Since it was/is a minor issue (you can work around that, e.g., Scott's answer), and as we may guess Pandas-dev crew is overloaded, it took some time to be addressed.
>
> One of these days I got an update on that issue as it was addressed ;)
>
> - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17093#issuecomment-859993083
>
> This edit is to (i) update this community on this particular matter, (ii) to thank and acknowledge all the open source developers -- the *Pandas' Developers*, in particular -- for the effort, diligence , and passion. Respect.

---

**Original post:**

I am having issues in transform to a group where the column used for grouping has NaN values.

The following code **used to work** until `pandas` version **0.19.1**. Now I've updated my environment to version **0.20.3** and it **works no more**.

The example code:

```
import numpy
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A':numpy.random.rand(100),
                       'B':numpy.random.rand(100)*10,
                       'C':numpy.random.randint(0,10,100)})
df.loc[:9,'C']=None
df.groupby('C')['B'].transform(lambda x:x.mean())
```

As of version `0.20.3` it raises the following error message:

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 90 elements, new values have 100 elements

After reading the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#na-and-nat-group-handling) I understand this a new behaviour; not a bug.

But it is not clear to me how to update my code, or work around that.

My goal is to have all the (output) values, but the ones where `C==None`, to be the result of each group's average (i.e, `mean`). The first 10 output' values (`df.loc[:9,...`) would be stay untouched (same as in '`B`').

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could still do `df.groupby('C')['B'].transform('mean')` right?

Comment: @JohnGalt Yes. But I should be able to use a (lambda) function as well (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), shouldn't I?

Comment: Thanks for raising this question! As for someone who is learning `pandas`, it helps understand why older SO answers don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's `mask` and uniquely identify those NaN with `cumsum`:

```
new_c = df['C'].mask(df['C'].isnull(),df['C'].isnull().cumsum())
df.groupby(new_c)['B'].transform('mean')
```

Or, if you testing some more complicated function

```
df.groupby(new_c)['B'].transform(lambda x: x.mean())
```

Output:

```
Out[54]:

0     5.249441
1     4.987245
2     5.245857
3     6.450159
4     4.017234
5     4.421589
6     3.673986
7     4.746087
8     5.841651
9     5.394510
10    4.421589
11    4.421589
12    4.746087
13    4.746087
14    6.450159
15    6.450159
16    3.813816
17    5.249441
18    5.841651
19    3.813816
20    3.673986
21    4.017234
22    6.450159
23    3.673986
24    4.987245
25    5.245857
26    4.017234
27    4.017234
28    6.450159
29    4.987245
....
```

Comment: I don't understand the "uniquely identify" idea. If you use the `cumsum` values inplace of the `NaN`s, you'll generate artificial information to the data. The "mean" values after that will consider those (`[0:9]`) points as valid ones. That is how I got it. Could you clarify that point, please? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, Brandt, since we can't use null in the groups any longer, you need to replace that null with something.  If you just blanket replace null with a value, then your mean will be an average of values 0:9.  But my understanding is that you really wanted just that value itself, so what I have done is to create and artifical group of the NaN using isnull, which returns True, then cumsum that to get a unique value for each NaN.  And when you group on this unique value it will average that one value and return that value.

Comment: @ScottBoston - `df.groupby('C')['B'].transform('mean')` still works without the need for masking.

Comment: @JohnGalt But what if he needed to use lambda function for something more complex?

Comment: Hm. I like it. I have to think a bit to see how that fit, but looks attractive. For purely random data it is a solution. Will push to my case and see how it works. Cheers.

Comment: @JohnGalt I get NaN's for those first ten values.

Comment: @JohnGalt It does work indeed. BTW, I learned that one from you ;)

Comment: Indeed, John, after your suggestion, I started thinking whether it is indeed a new behaviour (a "feature" so to say) or bug. Clearly, no doubts here, the same operation is showing two different behaviours! Which I guess is never meant...

Comment: @ScottBoston You said to John "`I get NaN's for those first ten values.`", actually that is the expected behaviour. If the column you are grouping has invalid entries, you *probably* don't want to consider those rows at all; by all means, they should compose a group "NaN" by themselves. Consider the following dataframe: `df = pandas.DataFrame({'A':numpy.random.rand(20),'B':[ i//5 for i in range(20) ],'C':numpy.random.randint(0,5,20)})` and see what happens in both cases (your and John's). Cheers

Comment: @JohnGalt I created an issue on pandas about that ambiguous behaviour: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17093 . Let's see what is gong on. Thanks