# Fill NA using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with NA values in my price column. I want to fill the na values with a groupby statement.

```
df['price'] = df.groupby(['manufacturer','type','year'])['price'].tranform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

However, I'm receiving the following Value error: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 403794 elements, new values have 421603 elements.

The shape of the dataframe is `(421603, 26)`

Can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`transform` has issues with missing values in `groupby` even if the `dropna` parameter is set to false (see [Handling NA in groupby + transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333681/handling-na-in-groupby-transform)). A small example for a dataframe raising issues would be

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'manufacturer':['a','a','b','c','c','a'],
     'type':[1,1,2,3,4,1],
     'year':[1999,1999,1999,1999,None,1999],
     'price':[None,111,1,2,3,None]})
```

You can use two workarounds. You can use a mask as described in the aforementioned post or you could exchange the `transform` with and `apply` which works with the `dropna=False` parameter.

```
df.groupby(['manufacturer','type','year'],dropna=False)['price']\
    .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```